# Qual a melhor forma de iterar objetos em um HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Qual é a melhor forma de iterar os objetos em um `HashMap` no Java de forma a ter acesso à chave e ao valor de cada entrada?

Comment: Você quer iterar cada entrada (chave+valor), somente os valores, ou somente as chaves?

Comment: @jpkrohling quero iterar sobre cada entrada, para ter acesso às duas propriedades.

Comment: Então acho que a solução do @Ecil parece a que melhor te atende :-)

Comment: Foi o que achei mais interessante. Ainda vou deixar o tópico aberto mais um tempo para estimular o pessoal a participar hehehe.

Answer (score 50):

Eu gosto de usar o laço `for` pois o código fica mais enxuto:

```java
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> pair : myHashMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(pair.getKey());
    System.out.println(pair.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Curto e claro, como deve ser ;)

Comment: Tem muita gente que frequentemente escreve código poluído por não conhecer os detalhes e as novidades da linguagem, como eu mesmo já fiz diversas vezes.

Comment: E além de tudo parece que esta é a forma mais otimizada. [Fonte 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826384/java-iteration-through-a-hashmap-which-is-more-efficient) e [fonte 2](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/01/performance-comparison-of-different-ways-to-iterate-over-hashmap/).

Answer (score 13):

Usando o método `entrySet()`,
Exemplo:

```java
public static void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap

Edit.:
Segundo a dica do (Vitor de Mario) vai uma breve explicação entre a diferença do `entrySet()` e do `LinkedHashMap<K,V>`.

O `entrySet()` não garante a ordem de iteração, já o `LinkedHashMap<K,V>` vai iterar exatamente na ordem que estiver apresentando no array.
Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java

Comment: Recomendo também usar o LinkedHashMap como implementação, se você quer iterar.

Comment: @VitorDeMario pode postar um exemplo para nós?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan o Guerra acabou de editar, é exatamente o q ele disse

Comment: Editei o posto @DeividiCavarzan, obrigado pela dica Vitor

Comment: Pra ajudar em demais dúvidas sobre maps (e collections): http://i.imgur.com/ox9SLL9.png

Comment: A resposta da sua fonte é de 2009, e já não é o melhor jeito de se iterar. O motivo é que, provavelmente, esta fosse uma solução mais compatível com JVMs sem suporte a genéricos, ou ainda por falta de suporte ao for() com iterador. Hoje em dia é bem mais fácil usar for(), iterando o elemento, ao invés de usar o iterador explicitamente e dar um cast.

Answer (score 9):

Pode utilizar operações funcionais:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
   System.out.println("key: " + key + ", value: " + value);
});
```

#### Funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/oaDFbv).

Comment: Muito bom para operações simples, mas para o meu caso que um trecho do código poderia lançar exceção, resolvi utilizar a resposta de `for` logo abaixo visto que o contorno com `try` `catch` ficaria ruim e o método pai já estava com a flag `throws Exception`, então tem que ter isso em mente

Answer (score 6):

```java
    Map<Integer,String> mapa=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    mapa.put(1, "ze");
    mapa.put(2, "mane");
    Set<Integer> chaves = mapa.keySet();  
    for (Iterator<Integer> it = chaves.iterator(); it.hasNext();){  
        Integer chave = it.next();  
        if(chave != null){  
            System.out.println(chave + mapa.get(chave));  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Criar um Set<Integer> e depois dar um "map.get()" é pedir pra ter problemas... Mais fácil iterar direto as entradas, ao invés de copiar as chaves e iterar o Set<Integer>.

Answer (score 2):

Existe também a opção de utilizar a biblioteca [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Dê uma olhada na [API](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) e na [Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Maps) da classe Maps.

Tem vários métodos interessantes, como por exemplo *difference* para obter a diferença entre 2 mapas, *transform**, *filter**, etc. Dependendo do que você quer fazer, utilizar um desses métodos para transformar, filtrar, etc. pode gerar um código mais simples e fácil de ler.